Group by and then conditionally perform functions based on different column values
I am trying to reduce the number of records in a data frame by grouping by x, then conditionally performing filtering depending on the group's values of column y and z.
Here's what I have so far:
# Required packages
library(tidyverse)

# Data Filtering
job_history <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                          
                          y = c("Hire", "Data Change", "Leave of Absence", "Hire", "Termination", "Hire", "Termination", "Rehire", "Transfer", "Hire", "Termination", "Rehire", "Termination"),
                          
                          z = as.Date(c("2024-01-01", "2024-02-01", "2024-03-01", "2024-01-01", "2024-02-01", "2024-01-01", "2024-02-01", "2024-03-01", "2024-04-01", "2024-01-01", "2024-02-01", "2024-03-01", "2024-04-01")))

# Group_by and conditionally filter
job_history %>% 
  
  group_by(x) %>% 
  
# Count the number of hire, termination, and rehire records
  mutate(hires   = sum(y == "Hire"),
         terms   = sum(y == "Termination"),
         rehires = sum(y == "Rehire")) %>% 
  
  case_when(
# If there is 1 hire record and no terms or rehires, filter for the latest record
    (hires = 1 & terms = 0 & rehires = 0) ~ filter(z = max(z)),
# If there is 1 hire and 1 term record, filter for the termination record
    (hires = 1 & terms = 1 & rehires = 0) ~ filter(y == "Termination"),
# If there is 1 of each record, filter for the term record and the latest record
    (hires = 1 & terms = 1 & rehires = 1) ~ filter(y == "Termination") | z = max(z)),
# If there is 1 hire, 2 term, and 1 rehire record, filter for both termination records
    (hires = 1 & terms = 2 & rehires = 1) ~ filter(y == "Termination")
  )

Desired output is like this:
x       y                   z
1       Leave of Absence    2024-03-01
2       Termination         2024-02-01
3       Termination         2024-02-01
3       Transfer            2024-04-01
4       Termination         2024-02-01
4       Termination         2024-04-01


Welcome to SO. You'll get better help if you describe your filtering conditions.
Try this:
# For each "x", keep the terminations or the latest event
filter(job_history, .by = x, y == "Termination" | z == max(z))
# A tibble: 6 × 3
      x y                z         
  <dbl> <chr>            <date>    
1     1 Leave of Absence 2024-03-01
2     2 Termination      2024-02-01
3     3 Termination      2024-02-01
4     3 Transfer         2024-04-01
5     4 Termination      2024-02-01
6     4 Termination      2024-04-01

Alternative solution
Not the best solution!, but closer to the op's original reasoning. Define the groups, take what you want for each one and bind together.
# Create groups from different parameters
aux <- job_history %>% 
  count(x, y) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = y, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  transmute(
    x, 
    group_id = case_when(
      Hire == 1 & Termination == 0 & Rehire == 0 ~ "a",
      Hire == 1 & Termination == 1 & Rehire == 0 ~ "b",
      Hire == 1 & Termination == 1 & Rehire == 1 ~ "c",
      Hire == 1 & Termination == 2 & Rehire == 1 ~ "d",
      TRUE ~ "other"))

#
job_output <- bind_rows(
  # Group "a"
  job_history %>% 
    inner_join(filter(aux, group_id == "a"), by = "x") %>% 
    filter(z == max(z)), 
  
  # GRoup "b"
  job_history %>% 
    inner_join(filter(aux, group_id == "b"), by = "x") %>% 
    filter(y == "Termination"),
  
  # Group "c"
  job_history %>% 
    inner_join(filter(aux, group_id == "c"), by = "x") %>% 
    filter(y == "Termination" | z == max(z)), 
  
  # Group "d" 
  job_history %>% 
    inner_join(filter(aux, group_id == "d"), by = "x") %>% 
    filter(y == "Termination"))

> job_output
# A tibble: 6 × 4
      x y                z          group_id
  <dbl> <chr>            <date>     <chr>   
1     1 Leave of Absence 2024-03-01 a       
2     2 Termination      2024-02-01 b       
3     3 Termination      2024-02-01 c       
4     3 Transfer         2024-04-01 c       
5     4 Termination      2024-02-01 d       
6     4 Termination      2024-04-01 d 


Very elegant thanks. I edited my post to clarify the filtering conditions. I think your suggestion gets me close enough, I will edit my code and try again.

@DerekBussman, if all "x" have at least one "Hire" (wich is the case on the sample data), you don't need to check this condition. Is this true on your real data?

This is awesome thank you!! Your alternative is exactly what I was looking for. The data quality is iffy so I need the separate groups in case I have to add other conditions down the line. Thanks for the learning opportunity.
